# Linq Query Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listbox

I have a listbox populated with entries from a table using Linq in C#.
I have the DisplayMemberPath set to "Country" Which is fine, no problems there.
When the country is selected from this listbox the selection changed event fires.
Here another linq query is ran to match the selected CustomerID with CustomerID's in an order table. This also works fine.

Now. Here's the problem. If I change selection from the first country I get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The problem is on the t2 variable here:

```
RESOLVED
```

Comment: You said, "This Code is property of Thomas Cawley - ITSligo Student". No, it's not. Look at the bottom line of this page: "user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)"

Comment: Just for if my assignment submission links as copied to this page my lecturer will see my comment and know it's mine

Comment: You're using [so] to submit your assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably raising an event when the SelectedIndex changes to -1, ie nothing is selected.  It would then raise another event for the selection changing to the new selection.

I would suggest putting logic in your event handler to cater for the situation when SelectedItem==null.  Probably clearing the other lists would be appropriate for this situation.

Comment: Spot On. I added this to the listbox changed event:                  if (lbxCountry.SelectedIndex == -1)
                lbxCountry.SelectedIndex = 0;                            and removed this from the combobox selection:                            if (lbxCountry.Items != null)
            lbxCountry.Items.Clear();                                         and it works now. Thanks Buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the breakpoint in your `SelectionChanged` event and check value of `((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue`. It might be `null` in this case.

**EDIT**

Put the `null check` in the handler since, when `ItemsSource is reset` for listbox `SelectedValue is set to null` and then reset to other value which will update your selection automatically -

```
private void lbxCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue != null)
    {
       var t2 = (from o in db.Orders
                where o.CustomerID == ((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString()
                select o);
       lbxCustCountry.ItemsSource = t2;
       Tab0Total.Text = lbxCustCountry.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the value is coming back null the second time. Any ideas how to rectify this??? Thanks

Comment: Can you show code for your `Combobx` in Xaml and what's the structure of its `ItemSource` object look like?

Comment: <ComboBox Name="cbxCountry" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Country" SelectedValuePath="Country" SelectionChanged="cbxCountry_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></ComboBox>

Comment: And what about `ItemsSource`? What's the collection look like?

Comment: You have set 'SelectedValuePath` also as `Country`. So, how can you compare it with `CustomerId` in event handler?

Comment: lbxCountry.ItemsSource = t1;

Comment: Can you edit the question and post all relevant code there? Not just `t1` but how you generating this `t1`.

Comment: Combobox populated with table entries on loaded event and displayed as countries. When a country is selected, a listbox is populated with customers from that country. When a customer is selected, a Second listbox is populated with orders by this customer. This all works for the first run. However if I try to select a different country from the ComboBox or a different Customer from the first listbox I get the null error where a selectedvalue returns null.